# If a polynomial is the zero function, then all coefficients are $0$

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra done right by Axler, the theorem is given as follows:

> Suppose $a_0, \ldots, a_m \in F$. If $$a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_mz^m=0$$
> for every $z\in F$, then $a_0=\dots=a_m=0$.

In the proof, the author says "we will prove the contrapositive. If not all the coefficients are $0$, then by changing $m$ we can assume $a_m\neq 0$."

What does "by changing $m$ we can assume $a_m\neq 0$" mean?

Comment: It may be that $a_m=0$ but a previous one is not.  So just eliminate all the "later" zeros and reindex the first non-zero coefficient (from the end) to occur at $m$.

Comment: @Randall That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this is not true for general $F$.  For example, over $\mathbb{F_2}$, $x + x^2 = 0$ for every $x$ (i.e. for $x=0$, $x=1.$)  However, it is true in fields of characteristic $0$, so I assume Axler must be assuming $F$ has characteristic $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard re-indexing trick to simplify the notation in an argument.  By assumption, some coefficient must not be $0$.  If $a_m \neq 0$, then carry the proof forward.  Else, $a_m=0$, but some other coefficient is not (by assumption).  We can find the "last" non-zero coefficient reading left to right--say it is $a_k$--so that $a_i=0$ for all $i >k$ yet $a_k \neq 0$.  Ignoring these final $0$s, you now have an expression
$$
a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_kz^k=0
$$
where $a_k \neq 0$.  But this is the exact same form as the first case when $a_m \neq 0$ when we imagine that $k=m$, so you may as well just assume that from the start.  That's all the author is saying.